# Azure SQL Data Warehouse - Slow LEFT JOIN with temporary table

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, temp-tables, azure-synapse

I run a very simple Query (see below) in my "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" and it takes 5 seconds. If I run the same Query in "Azure SQL Server" it takes 0 seconds which seems more normal. (This Query is basically a bunch of LEFT JOINS without condition as you will see from the execution plan if you run it.)

How is it possible that this takes 5 seconds?

```
CREATE TABLE #output(
  val INT
 )

INSERT INTO #output VALUES (1)

SELECT 
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output),
 (SELECT val FROM #output)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still puzzled as to what's going on here

Comment: Have you tried

UPDATE STATISTICS #output

If different SQL engines are performing differently then it suggests that they're using different query plans. 

Updating the statistics on a temporary table can significanly improve the plan that's chosen. I know that SQL Server assumes there's only one record but the Datawarehouse version might not

Comment: It's only 1 record inserted in #output. And as I mentioned it takes no time on "Azure SQL Server". (I ran this in a loop to see the magnitude of the difference and what took 45 minutes in SQLDW took 4 seconds in SQL Server. So the difference is HUGE).

Comment: I have also updated statistics with CREATE STATISTICS stats_col1 on #output (val) but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

The proposition for Azure SQL Data Warehouse is double-digit terabytes of data and billions of rows.  That is what it is fundamentally designed for, so you may well find that with certain smaller queries, certain query patterns and smaller databases that they just won't perform, just as you would find loading 30TB into a SQL PaaS database wouldn't perform either.  In those cases you need to rethink your queries and whether or not you really want to run those queries there.  For example, in this case, a simple rewrite as a UNION query brought sub-second performance in my Azure SQL Data Warehouse, eg

```
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output
UNION ALL
SELECT val FROM #output


SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT 'a' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'e' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'f' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'g' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'h' s, val FROM #output
    ) x
PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR s In ( [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h] ) ) pvt


-- Use CTAS to materialise the pivot view if required
CREATE TABLE #output2
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    LOCATION = USER_DB,
    HEAP
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT 'a' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'e' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'f' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'g' s, val FROM #output
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'h' s, val FROM #output
    ) x
PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR s In ( [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h] ) ) pvt
```

If you really need the rows as columns you can always use `PIVOT`.  I had a similar issue recently when creating a big numbers table.  The original query used a loop which ok is generally bad practice but it runs in a few a seconds on vanilla SQL Server and is a one-time operation.  Performance was horrible on Azure SQL Datawarehouse so I simply ran the query on my local instance, copied the data out with `bcp` and fired it into the warehouse in a few minutes.  (I also sought out a more set-based way of generating a numbers table : )

We were also looking at using Change Data Capture (CDC) which is not yet available in the warehouse version of the product, so we looked at hosting the staging area in vanilla SQL Server, engaging CDC on those tables and handing off to the warehouse via SSIS and the CDC functions.  We've since rejected that but you get the idea; if you have genuine queries you need to perform but won't consider rewriting them or even consider having a conventional edition of SQL Server in a VM and then handing off to the warehouse, eg via SSIS, Polybase etc

HTH

(This should probably be moved to dba.stackexchange.com)

PS Just to rule out the obvious, I assume you know you could write this query simply and you've just written it this way to highlight an issue:

```
SELECT val, val, val, val, val, val, val
FROM #output
```

I did a bit more digging on this and found if you were connected to the master database then this query ran nice and fast.  You cannot use the `USE` statement to change database context in Azure SQL Data Warehouse but if you were connected via some client (eg SSIS, sqlcmd) then this could be a workaround.  I still stand by my original assertion that certain low-volume query patterns aren't particularly suited to this version of the product.  I was also looking at the `EXPLAIN` keyword which gives a kind of a query plan so you can get an idea of what's going on under the hood, but that's another story...